# asus G701VIK install windows M2 SSD

Tags: boot, live-usb, pcie, m2

I have an ASUS G701VIK where I have installed two NVME SSD 960 Pro M.2.
The system has Windows 10 running on the same two drives and works correctly.

On disk 1 (GPT) I have the following partitions:

- Recovery NTFS 450 MB
- FAT32 100Mb (EFI System Partition)
- Other 16Mb (Reserved Partition)
- C:(NTFS) 493 Gb (shrunk using Mini Tool Wizard to create the next)
- (Ext4) 460 GB

There is also a Disk 2, with just one NTFS Volume.

I have disable Secure Boot and Fast Boot on the BIOS of the machine.

I have created a bootable USB drive using Win32DiskImager, for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 17.04 with the same result.

The computer boots from the USB, during boot I modify the GRUB boot script to include:
nouveau.modeset=0 (that is necessary for the graphics card)
and also have tried adding nvme_load=YES
and remove quiet splash

If I go to the GRUB command line and type ls -all I get the list of devices, where the partition types are correctly recognized except for the 3rd one.

It also complains about some efi files being missing: tar.mod, sfs.mod, nilfs2.mod, minix.mod, afs.mod, affs.mod.

In all cases, the result is that during the installation process the only drive that is recognized is the USB Drive, but not the M2 SSD drives.

I have read many posts all in this and other forums but haven't found any that helps me. I have also contacted the manufacturer and I am waiting for an answer (not that I have great hopes of them solving the issue for me).

The idea is to setup dual boot with Windows 10.

I am quite newbie on Ubuntu and Linux in general. Please ask for anything you think may be relevant to the problem and I haven't mentioned.

[image: grub console]

[image: select disk to install]

EDIT: answering the questions below, there is no nvme driver in the list, just PCIe. The only errors are related to wifi
how to install the driver? is nvme_load the command?

Fast boot is disabled, as it is Secure Boot.

EDIT2: Adding links to the outputs of all 3 commands requested:
(I haven´t run nvme_load this time)

[lspci -k output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5wa61c0ue1n1ex/lspcik.txt?dl=0)
[lsblk output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/89l5sctlmgbjqtv/lsblk.txt?dl=0)
[dmesg output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbdnskrlec8her0/dmesg.txt?dl=0)

Comment: What I would do is install the boot loader on the ssd that you install Ubuntu on.  Have you done that?

Comment: No, I haven't. how can I do it? I am quite new to Linux.

Comment: the easiest way for you would probably be just reinstall it with a different, new downloaded ISO file, and for the select the SSD where you want to install it on as the boot loader location.

Comment: is this something I can do from Windows? What software do I need to use? Ubuntu doesn't see the SSD but GRUB does.

Comment: What happens if you put in the live USB flash drive and boot into it?

Comment: Ubuntu boots from the USB drive. the installer starts and when I get to the part where I must select the disk to install to, only /dev/sda (the USB drive) appears. The + and - icons are disabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63641/discussion-between-mathcubes-and-picarus).

Comment: You should boot the usb in live mode (as oppose to installer mode) and check whether the nvme drive is listed in `lspci -k` at all. If so, see if nvme is listed as driver in use. If so, check `lsblk` to see if the nvme drive is listed. If not, check with `dmesg` to see if there's any relavant error.

Comment: Check if Windows has enabled the fastboot feature as this locks down the hard drive

Comment: Can you just paste the *full* output of `lspci -k`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SATA Controller [RAID mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

[    9.805918] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Found 2 remapped NVMe devices.
[    9.805918] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Switch your BIOS from RAID to AHCI mode to use them.
```

dmesg has given you the solution. For whatever reason, the kernel requires the SATA controller to be in AHCI mode instead of RAID mode to allow you to use the two NVMe drives. So changing the mode in BIOS/UEFI settings should do.

Edit: apparently in some machines, the RAID mode is hardcoded and the user cannot make changes to that in the BIOS/UEFI settings. In that case, it is impossible (as of today, at least) to use the NVMe drives in Linux:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/aecec8b60422118b52e3347430ba9382e57d6d76

Also see replies in this thread for more details:

http://marc.info/?l=linux-ide&m=147709610621480&w=2

Your only chance will be to see if the vendor provides firmware update that allows you to change the mode to AHCI. You may also try request alternative firmware build by seeking technical support directly from the vendor, though you are likely to be out of luck on that.

Comment: The BIOS doesn't have an AHCI mode. In the SATA configuration there is only one mode: Intel RST Premium. The question is if Windows can manage the disks not being on RAID, how make Ubuntu do the same?

Comment: You can't. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/aecec8b60422118b52e3347430ba9382e57d6d76

Comment: To be honest I didn't understand why the ahci driver is involved at all. Apparently it's yet another dirty deed of Intel and some other vendors. If you are interested in the details maybe this the replies to this thread would help a bit: http://marc.info/?l=linux-ide&m=147709610621480&w=2

Comment: I wonder how these NVMe drives are exposed under Windows. As SATA drives maybe? A screenshot of your device manager expanded could be interesting. Not gonna help you getting out of this mess though.

Comment: TL;DR, say bye bye to Linux (not just Ubuntu) if you need to stick with this laptop and NVMe drives, at least for now.

Comment: @Picarus there's a BIOS (UEFI) update available https://www.asus.com/us/support/Download/3/877/0/3/ztMj51lsFVthDB7P/45/ . I wouldn't expect much luck though.

Comment: In my device manager, Storage controllers, the two controllers that appear are Intel Chipset SATA RAID Controller and Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller.

Comment: When Linus Torvalds says something is not possible I guess it is not going to be. I am going to give it a go with the BIOS update and see what happens if not I will contact ASUS. I need Linux to work.

Comment: Looking further in the Device Manager, If I look in the Disk Drives, the device appears as Device SCSI, parent Device: PCI (event tab)

Comment: @Picarus As I expected, they do not work as NVMe drives in Windows either, coz otherwise you should see both of them listed under Storage Controllers.

Comment: @Picarus I think one of the reasons they hardcoded RAID mode is that only the Intel specific driver would be used but never Microsoft's AHCI driver.

Comment: The BIOS update hasn't worked. As a last resort before closing the topic, is there any option to make ubuntu use the drive as SCSI. Many thanks for your help I will accept your solution. To make things easier I suggest you update your answer to include the links  you have provided on the comments.

Comment: @Picarus Well no. The reason why they are listed as SCSI drives in Windows is, modern OSes have SCSI-ATA Translation Layer implemented for ATA drives. This is not specifically related to this NVMe behind AHCI scenario but a general case. That's also why SATA drives are listed as /dev/sdX and why the scsi disk driver (sd-mod) is involved.

Comment: then there is no option feasible. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP. You cannot imagine how much this means to me. And particularly when the answer is there is no solution it takes a lot of expertise to get to the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

the same with me, an HP EliteBook with M2 NGFF. Ubuntu live boot ok but can't install. Error noted that "Can't configure your hardware..."
My Solution: replace a HDD to SATA slot and change boot order to legacy, and then install Ubuntu on HDD and Windows 10 on M2 PCIe NGFF